# Universal app HttpClient header error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-rt

I'm creating  [universal application](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/building-universal-windows-apps) and I need to use Keep-Alive connection header for my requests. I have the code

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("connection", "Keep-Alive");
    var str = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return str;
}
```

but I catch exception **The header Connection has an empty value.**
Please somebody show me where is my mistake and how I can set **Connection** header to **Keep-Alive**

I've added screenshot from Wireshark where you can see **Connection** header value by default (if remove *client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("connection", "Keep-Alive");*)

[image: Connection header by default]

Comment: You should better clarify what stack are you using, `System.Net.Http` or `Windows.Web.Http`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` requests are `Keepp-Alive` by default.